# python sqlite3 Getting error: sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Can you help me, I wrote this code:

```
class Favorits(object):
    def __init__(self, graph_):
        self.graph_ = graph_
        self.conn3 = sqlite3.connect('C:/C/V2.db')

    def add_(self):
        с3 = self.conn3.cursor()
        с3.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fav")
        t_count = с3.fetchall()
        self.conn3.commit()
        t_count = t_count[0][0]

        to_add_rus = self.graph_.text_rus.get('1.0', 'end')
        to_add_eng = self.graph_.text_eng.get('1.0', 'end')
        to_add_esp = self.graph_.text_esp.get('1.0', 'end')
        с3.execute("INSERT INTO fav VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (t_count + 1,    to_add_rus, to_add_eng, to_add_esp))
        self.conn3.commit()

    def rem_(self):
        c4 = self.conn3.cursor()

        idx = (self.graph_.word_.f_0_to_remove)
        idx = idx[0]
        print(idx)
        c4.execute("DELETE FROM fav WHERE id_=?", (idx,))
        self.conn3.commit()
```

This is a class which I use to add and remove different rows from db (using Tkinter as GUI).
So basically I'm trying to make two different connections to the same db via two different cursors (in order to be able to add and remove words from it). And I constantly get this error:
self.conn3.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

I already tried differend options, makin' two different cursors, etc. nothing helps.

Comment: Sqlite isn't designed for concurrency. If you have long writes (>5 secs) then your other queries will time out. If you crashed everything, it's possible that you have a journal file next to the db of unwritten changes. Deleting that will then free up the database for new connections, but the solution overall is probably to use a different technology.

Comment: The other thing you might be able to look into is the [WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), I'm not sure if that will be suitable for your purpose. But I think the immediate issue is that you crashed and have uncommited changes in a journal file that tell other connections that the DB is locked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the database connection after opening it. Otherwise the connection persists, and so the database believes an edit is underway so locks itself.

You can break the connection with the command `self.conn3.close()`.

Comment: SQLite doesn't see multiple connections as a database lock. You can have multiple readers, for example. More likely is that they have uncommited changes in a journal file that's acting like a mutex.